# Checking accuracy of IDW using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, inverse-distance-weighted

I performed IDW using ArcGIS on 121 evenly distributed samples and generated a surface.

How do I check the accuracy of the method?

Answer (score 3):

In order to evaluate the accuracy of your interpolated surface you either need:

- additional samples

or

- to remove some random samples prior to interpolation

These are used to cross-validate your result.

On your created IDW layer you right-click and choose **Validation/Prediction**.

This link actually describes the process: https://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/using-validation-to-assess-models.htm